# How to create 1024x1024 RGB bitmap image of white?

Tags: c#

It's embarrassing to ask this question but can't find an answer.

I tried this in vain.

```
Image resultImage = new Bitmap(image1.Width, image1.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

using (Graphics grp = Graphics.FromImage(resultImage)) 
{
    grp.FillRectangle(
        Brushes.White, 0, 0, image1.Width, image1.Height);
    resultImage = new Bitmap(image1.Width, image1.Height, grp);
}
```

I basically want to fill a 1024x1024 RGB bitmap image with white in C#. How can I do that?

Comment: You are looking solution for your problem but my problem solved with your code, thanks :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are assigning a new image to `resultImage`, thereby overwriting your previous attempt at creating a white image (which should succeed, by the way).

So just remove the line

```
resultImage = new Bitmap(image1.Width, image1.Height, grp);
```

Answer (score 47):

You almost had it:

```
private Bitmap DrawFilledRectangle(int x, int y)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(x, y);
    using (Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        Rectangle ImageSize = new Rectangle(0,0,x,y);
        graph.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, ImageSize);
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

Answer (score 24):

Another approach,

Create a unit bitmap

```
var b = new Bitmap(1, 1);
b.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.White);
```

And scale it

```
var result = new Bitmap(b, 1024, 1024);
```

Comment: Careful! When you use `Color.FromArgb()` you will get a gradient when scaling the bitmap. Better use the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12502497/489772) from @LeeHarrison.

Answer (score 6):

[Graphics.Clear(Color)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.clear?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1024, 1024);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)){g.Clear(Color.White);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, a *BitmapSource* might suit. You can quickly fill a byte array with the *0xff* (i.e. white) using *Enumerable.Repeat()*.

```
int w = 1024;
int h = 1024;
byte[] pix = Enumerable.Repeat((byte)0xff, w * h * 4).ToArray();
SomeImage.Source = BitmapSource.Create(w, h, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32, null, pix, w * 4);
```