# Byte array to image exception, parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, image

i have a trouble converting byte array to an image by common methods for example:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
{
    return Image.FromStream(ms); ->exception
}
```

and

```
System.Drawing.ImageConverter converter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
Image img = (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(ImgInBytes); -> exception
```

The **exception** is
**Parameter is not valid**

moreover, i used a 4 byte array length which was initiated by zero value.

it was supposed to show a black image but it didn't

Comment: you think you can make a image from 4 bytes? That would be just enough data for one pixel. But not actually wich color depth to use or any of the thousand other important inforamtions. You should propably not try to create a image from scratch. Create it from a existing soruce until you got the hang of the basics.

Comment: Show the `byteArrayIn` variable. If you just want to create an empty black image, what stops you from using a new Bitmap? Moreover, from where does your information come that it is supposed to be a black image? How would you decide on width & height of a picture?

Comment: @Christopher why there is not any limitation on byte[] size?

Comment: @Icepickle it was a test for more information

Comment: @Mr.AF that doesn't mean that any arbitrary content is valid; what format are you trying to represent (streams are broadly comparable to files: it isn't just raw bitmap data); the *header* for most image formats is more than 4 bytes

Comment: @MarcGravell so if i use a biger byte[] i would get supposed result?

Comment: @Mr.AF: No, giving otehr peopels code more then 4 bytes of junk data will not result in a valid image. The solution is **not giving junk data**.

Comment: @Christopher i need to reach to a good concept because i should avoid future troubles in server when there is not valid byte[] size isn't it?

Comment: @Mr.AF using a `byte[]` that consists of a valid image header (for some format) and a valid image payload (for that same format) would give you the supposed result; making it bigger *by itself*: won't. This seems like an expectation failure. If what you want is a black image: start with a new `Bitmap` instance and use the API to tell is what you want. Heck, you could then write it to a file (or stream) to *find out* what a suitable correct `byte[]` would look like.

Comment: @MarcGravell good answer ,please post it .it's important concept which all need to know.

Comment: @MarcGravell how can i check is byte[] valid or not?

Comment: Maybe this [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZQsL3A) will help you find it out

Comment: @Mr.AF it isn't just about size: the contents matter; the input needs to be a valid image format - `0 0 0 0` is *not* a valid image format. Most images consist of an identification token (png always starts 137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10, for example) - then format-specific encoded metadata - dimensions, color depth, possibly a color palette, maybe date/location/tool metadata; then *finally* some pixel data, which could use a range of encodings... and that's assuming it is pixed-based (vs vector-based)

Comment: @MarcGravell Great answer .please post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i used a 4 byte array length which was initiated by zero value.

The API expects a valid image stream; 4 bytes with value zero is *not* a valid image stream. The method is going to inspect the stream, trying to identify the image format (streams are broadly comparable to files, except without any concept of a filename) - it isn't just looking for pixel data. That means it is going to be looking for an *image header* that it recognizes (for example, png always starts with the byte values 137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10); once it has identified the format, it'll want to decode the image header (dimensions, color depth, possibly a palette, etc), and then *finally* there might be some pixel data - or there might not, if it isn't a pixel format (it could be a vector image format). So; there's a *lot* more to consider than just some pixel data.

If you want a black image: perhaps start with `Bitmap` - maybe see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12502497/23354)